# Menú desplegable con valores leídos de base de datos y 1 preseleccionado

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy programando un backend para una pequeña aplicación en PHP y HTML para una academia de educación online. Tengo dudas al respecto de una parte de esta aplicación. Les adjunto imagen de la tabla de la base de datos donde se guardan los registros de una serie de artículos (más de 100 actualmente). Y cada articulo tiene asociado un curso (columna cursId).

[image: Base de datos, tabla "cursos_articles"]

Luego hay una segunda tabla llamada "cursos" donde hay toda la lista de cursos disponibles.

[image: Tabla "cursos"]

Dentro de la aplicación PHP el usuario entra a una primera página donde le aparece una tabla con todos los registros de articulos correspondientes a la tabla "cursos_articles". Cada registro lo puede editar, por lo que entra en una segunda página de la aplicación. Allí en teoría deberían de aparecer una serie de menús desplegables por si tiene que cambiar algo referente al artículo.

Tengo varios menús desplegados que deberían mostrar todas las opciones disponibles de una tabla de la bd y el usuario seleccionaría la que más le interesa. **La parte importante, la que no sé hacer, es que este menú desplegable debería mostrar como valor predeterminado el que ya está marcado en la base de datos.** El usuario debería elegir si lo mantiene o lo cambia.

Mi código, que no funciona, es este:

```
echo '<label for="CursId">Selecciona curs:</label>';
echo '<select class="form-control" name="CursId" id="CursId" value="'. $CursId.'">';
echo "<option>---Select subject---</option>";
global $dbho;
$llibres = $dbho->get_results("SELECT cursos.CursId, cursos.CursNom 
  FROM " . TCURSOS . " AS cursos
  INNER JOIN " . TCURSOS_ARTICLES . " AS cursos_articles ON cursos.CursId = cursos_articles.CursId
  GROUP BY cursos_articles.CursId
  ORDER BY cursos_articles.CursId ASC;");
foreach($llibres as $llibre){
$CursNom = $row->CursNom;
$CursId = $row->CursId;

echo "<option value=".$CursId." selected>".$CursNom."</option>"; 

}
echo "</select></div>
```

¿Alguna idea de cómo se puede hacer la pre-selección del valor?
Muchas gracias

Comment: Vos le pusiste selected a todas las opciones. La unica que deberia tenerlo es la que vos queres.

Comment: Entiendo, ¿entonces como me quedaría el código? ¿Donde debo corregir? Gracias por su pronta respuesta

Comment: La unica opcion que tiene que tener selected es la que vos queres que este seleccionada. Debererias sacar el selected para todas las opciones, y solo agregarlo en la que vos queres.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la columna de la BD que indica el valor que debería estar marcado y cuál de las tablas se encuentra? ¿Qué tipo de dato es: booleano, entero, varchar, char...?

Comment: En la base de datos la llave primaria es "relacio_id". Y el que a mí me interesa para este menú desplegable es "CursId". La tabla es "cursos_articles". Es un valor entero

Comment: En la pregunta dices esto: *La parte importante, la que no sé hacer, es que este menú desplegable debería mostrar como valor predeterminado **el que ya está marcado en la base de datos**.* Entonces, lo que queremos sabes es dónde, en qué columna, de la base de datos aparece el valor que debería estar marcado. Imagino que es una columna booleana o numérica que tiene el valor `1` o `0` o algo así.

Comment: @A.Cedano No entendí antes. La columna tiene valores que van del 1 al 17 (de momento, pero el número puedo aumentar). Representan cursos que desde la aplicación se pueden agregar o eliminar. Por eso, ahora son 17 pero podrían ser 15 o 24. Esto nunca lo puedo saber.

Comment: Ya pero ¿cuál es el criterio para saber cuál debe aparecer seleccionado? Eso tienes que decirlo tú y en base a eso podremos sugerirte algo. No podemos adivinar la lógica de tu programa.

Comment: @A.Cedano Perdón por mí poca claridad. La tabla "cursos_articles" que contiene todos los registros, tiene guardado que para "relacio_id" 4, el "CursId" es 16. La lista de todos los cursos está en la tabla "cursos".

Comment: No nos estamos entendiendo. Tú dices que de todas las filas una sola debe aparecer seleccionada por defecto. La pregunta es, ¿en base a **qué CRITERIO** se decide que esa fila debe ser la que se muestre seleccionada por defecto?

Comment: @A.Cedano A ver si ahora acierto con la respuesta: La aplicación tiene una primera pantalla, donde aparece en una tabla todos los registros existentes en la tabla "cursos_articles". Allí el usuario tiene un boton "Editar". Entonces en esa segunda pagina edita ese registro de la tabla. Allí es donde debería salir este menú desplegable para el curso. Quizá ahora me he explicado mejor.

Comment: Lo lamento pero no, no se entiende. Sugiero que edites la pregunta explicando con detalle la situación a ver si podemos entender. A veces ***el problema es que no sabemos explicar el problema***.

Comment: @A.Cedano Igual ahora he conseguido hacerme entender. ¿Alguna otra aclaración que deba hacer?

Comment: Ahora se tiene una idea más clara del contexto y de lo que quieres, pero insisto en lo mismo: **¿cuál es el CRITERIO para saber qué opción debe marcarse como seleccionada?** Te falta explicar eso con claridad, y es lo más importante del asunto. Lo puedes decir en una sola línea, pero no lo dices. ¿En base a qué criterio se decide que esta es la opción que debe aparecer como seleccionada con respecto a las demás opciones?

Comment: @A.Cedano Te agradezco que hayas tenido la paciencia de seguir respondiendo a pesar que he sido poco claro (involuntariamente). El criterio para saber qué opción debe marcarse como seleccionada es relacio_id= 1 le corresponde el CursId= 2. El criterio lo marca la base de datos (he puesto la imagen en mi pregunta editada). Por decirlo de alguna forma, el criterio se tiene que ir a buscar en la base de datos, tabla "cursos". Allí hay la columna "CursId" que es la que marca que curso debe estar seleccionado para cada artículo. Igual el planteamiento de mi aplicación es equivocado, no se.

Answer (score 2):

Debes tener una variable que contenga el curso que ya tiene seleccionado en la base de datos, y comparar todos los cursos que vas a mostrar antes de ponerlos en pantalla, después de eso te quedaría un código como este.

```
if ($IDcursoSeleccionado==$CursId){
    echo "<option value=".$CursId." selected>".$CursNom."</option>"; 
} else {
        echo "<option value=".$CursId.">".$CursNom."</option>"; 
}
```

De esta manera solo el curso que ya tienes seleccionado en la BD, aparecera con el selected

Comment: Le agradezco su respuesta. Pero no me queda claro ¿cómo creo la variable que contiene el curso que se debe mostrar como preseleccionado? Gracias

Comment: @ElliotFernandez aunque no lo creas, todas las dudas que estas planteando, el unico que las puede resolver sos vos. Cuando un usuario entra, y sin importar como armas la pantalla, como sabes que curso tiene seleccionado?